# Rails: link_to calls custom method in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking to use `link_to` to call a method in my controller. However, for some odd reason the route looks for the `show` method.

In my view:

```
<% @beverages.each do |beverage| %>
    ..
    <%= link_to 'Archive', beverages_archive_path(:id => beverage.id) %>
    ..
<% end %>
```

In my config/routes.rb

```
match 'beverages/archive' => 'beverages#archive'
```

In my beverages_controller.rb

```
  def archive
    beverage = Beverage.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
    #  format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: beverage }
    end
    # beverage.update_attribute('archive', true)
  end
```

When I click on the archive link in the view, the URL does change to: `http://localhost:3000/beverages/archive?id=11`, however I get the following error.

**The error I get:**
[image: error]
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Beverage with id=archive):
  app/controllers/beverages_controller.rb:46:in `show'

Any idea on what I am doing wrong? Your help is much appreciated!

PS. I also looked at [Rails 3 link_to delete destory method calls show method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203827/rails-3-link-to-delete-destory-method-calls-show-method)
but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Could you show your `routes.rb`? Probably you have something like `resources :beverages` above match line?

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738573/link-to-action-create-going-to-index-rather-than-create

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried this in your routes?

```
match 'beverages/:id/archive' => 'beverages#archive', as: :beverages_archive
```

This will create the beverages_archive_path method for you. Also, as you are looking for a specific beverage, use :id inside the route so that it knows where to take the id parameter from.

Apart from that, you can always tell a link specifically which controller and action to link to by doing:

```
link_to "Label", :controller => :my_controller, :action => :index
```

Taken from here: [Ruby on rails 3 link_to controller and action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607155/ruby-on-rails-3-link-to-controller-and-action)

Comment: Rails 4 does not like the word "match"; I would suggest using 'post' or 'get' instead.

Answer (score 5):

Use the other notation (not `match`) instead.

```
resources :beverages do
  collection do
    get :archive
  end
 end
```

Try this one out and let me know if something went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There's not quite enough information here to know why `beverages_archive_path` works in your app -- one problem is that your routes file does not define a name for your `beverages#archive` route. What you want is something like:

```
match 'beverages/archive' => 'beverages#archive', :as => :beverages_archive
```

or better yet use resourceful routing conventions like so:

```
resources :beverages do
  collection do
    get :archive
  end
end
```

What's happening is that you have a `beverages#show` route that matches `/beverages/:id`, and this is what `/beverages/archive` matches (with `:id => 'archive'`).